# How can I close my application when I switch to another application

Tags: android

hi all help me I am kind new in android developing How can I close my application when I switch to another application example through my app has a link to navigate and I want my app will be closed after the start of navigation

Comment: call `this.finish();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you wish to exit all open activities not just the current one,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse('...'));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then finish your current activity by calling the finish method,

```
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply call `finish()` after you have started the other app and your activity will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following,

```
 protected void onPause(){
      super.onPause();   
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
     intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     startActivity(intent);
     finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use finish() to destroy your activity

Suppose u r going to start another activity like

```
   Intent i=new Intent(Activit1.this, Activity2.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   finish();    //here your activity is destroyed and when you press the back button it wont take you to your 1st activity
```

Comment: Could you provide a code example or a link to the API of the `finish`  method? Thanks!